# Dataframe vs Numpy array in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a questions regarding dataframe and numpy arrays in Python. When we read any csv file using pandas, it is stored in a dataframe. Dataframe is useful when it comes to data manipulations, viewing data in columns etc. However some preprocessing functions such as Imputer do not work on Dataframes. For these functions we have to get the data in numpy arrays which makes the data manipulation difficult 
In following code I while y is stored as int64 array, X is ndarray object of numpy module. I can not use append function on X. Can anyone suggest how to correct this

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('titanic.csv')
y = dataset.iloc[:,1].values
X= dataset.iloc[:,2:12].values
```

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example of the append code with sample data, and tell us what error you get?

Answer (score 0):

You really should give us more information about what you want/expect, but here's my guess:

```
In [6]: Y=np.arange(3)                   # 1d
In [7]: X=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)     # 2d
In [8]: np.column_stack([Y,X])
Out[8]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 1,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 2,  8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

This should be the same as

```
dataset.iloc[:,[1,2,3,...12]].values
```

though why you didn't do `dataset.iloc[:,1:12]`?